# Casting JDBC JNDI datasources from Tomcat - ComboPooledDataSource

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Can somebody please put me out of my misery and explain why this happens and how to fix it.

1. a tomcat datasource

   ```
   <Resource name="MY_JDBC_NAME" auth="Container"
     driverClass="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     jdbcUrl="MyURL"
     user="MyUser"
     password="MyPassword"                                                     
     factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
     type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
     maxPoolSize="25"   
     minPoolSize="5"
     acquireIncrement="1"
     acquireRetryAttempts = "2"
     idleConnectionTestPeriod = "60"
     testConnectionOnCheckout = "true"
     preferredTestQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
   ```

   />
2. a lookup

   ```
   ComboPooledDataSource ds = (ComboPooledDataSource) ctx.lookup(     "java:comp/env/MY_JNDI_NAME");
   ```

This results in the baffling

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource cannot be cast to com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am using this,
may be it works for you also perfectly, try with this,

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
```

....

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("MY_JDBC_NAME");
```

Comment: Thanks yes that normal scenario does work. However the reason I have to cast the datasoure to its actual type com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource is because I require this to set up a DCN Listener (Database Change Notification). Therefore I need some way to convert it/ cast it.